# clearing old page data in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am doing simple showing table data and creating table data using angular js.

```
<select  ng-model="operation" ng-change="operationSelect()">
    <option value="showtable">View table data</option>
    <option value="inserttable">Insert table data</option>
</select>               

<form  ng-submit="formSubmit()">
    <select  ng-model="textbox">
        <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
        <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
        <option value="xxxx">xxx</option>
        <option value="xxx">xxxxxx</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
</form>
```

formSubmit() is function which populate the page respectively. Now whenever i select another option from select menu, i want current page data to be cleared.
e.g if i select to insert operation, table data should be cleared.I tried doing something like this

```
$scope.operationSelect = function(){
    $scope.choose =$scope.operation   ;

    if ($scope.choose == "showtable"){

        $scope.showtable = true;
        $scope.showinsert =false;        
    } else if ($scope.choose== "inserttable"){

        $scope.showtable = false;
        $scope.showinsert =true;            
    }         
}
```

its not working correctly.If i show table data then insert data and then if i select show table data, i will have old show table view displayed on page.How can i clear the old page data

Comment: What's the data you want to clear? I don't quite understand.

Comment: old populated page, which i am just hiding with ng-show whih i want to clear it.

Comment: Which scope variable is "old populated page"?

Comment: its not variable its old div which was populated with table data, i want this div cleared when i select insert operation. i cant do innerHTML='' as it destroy data completely

Comment: Show the relevant view and controller code for the table. Question can't be answered without you providing the proper information

Comment: Let me explain it in different way
I go to webpage to buy car.
I select car AUDI mode A3 and submit it shows me audi A-8 details.
Now from list i select BMW, now when i select BMW from list, i want page which is showing AUDI details cleared as soon as i select BMW from menu

Comment: you clear the data that is used in the view to display the car. SHow that code. Or you redirect to path that contains the path variable used to define the car and controller runs again with new data

Comment: thx that helped, i just set the jason variable to null at the start of function and it worked.

Comment: @charlietfl Guess you gotta post that as an answer now...